# Как зафиксировать сайт при открытии меню на Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Всем привет. У меня есть сайт, который делаю. http://advokat-v-spb.ru/
В нем имеется фиксированное меню. При открытии меню, срабатывает overflow:hidden для html и body, чтоб наверняка :)

Но есть такой друг, как safari, который мучает сайт. У самого меню есть элемент скролла, т.к. высокое меню, выходит, что скролится весь сайт, при том, что его не трогают, а только меню. Решилась проблема так.

height:100vh;
overflow:hidden;

да, все заработало шикарно, даже в сафари все супер, ничего не листается, меню работает превосходно, но проблема в том, что пользователя кидает в самое начало страницы, т.к. я понимаю, что обрезается сверху. Кто знает аналогичные решения или как оставить пользователя в том же месте? Спасибо

Comment: сделайте прозрачную подложку под меню на всю область страницы

Comment: Ответы - в ответы. А вместа сайта пример добавь.

Answer (score 0):

Можно после закрытия вернуть пользователя на то же место где остановились. В переменную js нужно записывать положение скрола, когда меню закрывается плавно промотать страницу на прежнее положение с помощью того же js. Но это похоже на костыль...